# Numpy genfromtxt - Is it possible to set default type for missing fields when reading file?

Tags: python, numpy

I am using numpy genfromtxt to read in CSV data files which I subsequently stack into a single structured numpy array.  However, I am running into some problems because in some of the files all data are missing from some fields.  Because of this, when I try and stack the data I get a "TypeError: Incompatible type" for the field with all missing data.

Is there a way to handle this by setting a default missing_values dtype in genfromtxt, or by somehow handling the type mismatch when stacking the arrays?

Note, I do not know what the field datatypes are going to be ahead of time.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.lib.recfunctions as RF

#=====================================================
#------------ file test0.csv ---------- 
# fld1, fld2, fld3, fld4, fld5
# aaa, 1, , 3.0, 4
# bbb, 2, , 4.1, 3
# ccc, 3, , 5.2, 2
# ddd, 4, , 6.3, 1
# 
#------------ file test1.csv ---------- 
# fld1, fld2, fld3, fld4, fld5
# aaa, 1, 2.0, 3.0, 4
# bbb, 2, 2.1, 4.1, 3
# ccc, 3, 2.2, 5.2, 2
# ddd, 4, 2.3, 6.3, 1
#    
#====================================================================
fn0 = r'C:\temp\test0.csv'
fn1 = r'C:\temp\test1.csv'

a0 = np.genfromtxt(fn0, dtype=None, delimiter=',', names=True)
a1 = np.genfromtxt(fn1, dtype=None, delimiter=',', names=True)

da = RF.stack_arrays((a0,a1))
```

Comment: have you tried the `missing_values` and `filling_values` options to [`genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html)?

Comment: So all files have the same header, and same number of delimiters?

Comment: I thought `missing_values` was for replacing text that represented missing values.  My files do not have text designating missing values, only empty entries

Comment: yes, same header and same delimiters.  Though I don't know the structure ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

With your samples `a2.dtype` is

```
dtype=[('fld1', 'S3'), ('fld2', '<i4'), 
       ('fld3', '<f8'), ('fld4', '<f8'), ('fld5', '<i4')
```

but for `a1` `('fld3', '?')` because there's no data to deduce a type from.

If I define a dtype list

```
dt=['S3',int,float,float,int]
a2 = np.genfromtxt(txt2, dtype=dt, delimiter=',', names=True)
a1 = np.genfromtxt(txt1, dtype=dt, delimiter=',', names=True)
```

then the arrays have a common `dtype` and I can concatenate (no need for the `RF` version):

```
In [25]: np.concatenate([a1,a2],axis=0)
Out[25]: 
array([(b'aaa', 1, nan, 3.0, 4), (b'bbb', 2, nan, 4.1, 3),
       (b'ccc', 3, nan, 5.2, 2), (b'ddd', 4, nan, 6.3, 1),
       (b'aaa', 1, 2.0, 3.0, 4), (b'bbb', 2, 2.1, 4.1, 3),
       (b'ccc', 3, 2.2, 5.2, 2), (b'ddd', 4, 2.3, 6.3, 1)], 
      dtype=[('fld1', 'S3'), ('fld2', '<i4'), ('fld3', '<f8'), ('fld4', '<f8'), ('fld5', '<i4')])
```

I don't see a way around making an explicit list like `dt`.  There's nothing in the parameters, that I can see, which lets me say, for example that when using `dtype=None`, unknown columns should be `float`.

Once created, it's going to take a lot of work to change the dtype of selected fields to make them compatible.  Changing names is easy.  But changing field dtype most likely will require making a new empty array and copying fields.

Look at the `a1.itemsize` and `a2.itemsize`.  They are respectively 20 and 27.

==========================

Here's an example of changing the dtype after loading.  `a1n` and `a2n` are the arrays created with `dtype=None`:

Empty array with shape from `a1`, but dtype from `a2`:

```
In [31]: a1nn = np.zeros(a1n.shape, dtype=a2n.dtype)
In [32]: for n in a1nn.dtype.names:  
   ....:     a1nn[n]=a1n[n]     # copy fields by name
   ....:     
In [33]: a1nn
Out[33]: 
array([(b'aaa', 1, 0.0, 3.0, 4), (b'bbb', 2, 0.0, 4.1, 3),
       (b'ccc', 3, 0.0, 5.2, 2), (b'ddd', 4, 0.0, 6.3, 1)], 
      dtype=[('fld1', 'S3'), ('fld2', '<i4'), ('fld3', '<f8'), ('fld4', '<f8'), ('fld5', '<i4')])
In [34]: np.concatenate([a1nn,a2n])
Out[34]: 
array([(b'aaa', 1, 0.0, 3.0, 4), (b'bbb', 2, 0.0, 4.1, 3),
       (b'ccc', 3, 0.0, 5.2, 2), (b'ddd', 4, 0.0, 6.3, 1),
       (b'aaa', 1, 2.0, 3.0, 4), (b'bbb', 2, 2.1, 4.1, 3),
       (b'ccc', 3, 2.2, 5.2, 2), (b'ddd', 4, 2.3, 6.3, 1)], 
      dtype=[('fld1', 'S3'), ('fld2', '<i4'), ('fld3', '<f8'), ('fld4', '<f8'), ('fld5', '<i4')])
```

`genfromtxt` filled the missing fields with `np.nan`, but this route used `0`.

`RF` has a function that copies arrays field by field, but does so recursively when the `dtype` is nested.